# Change data in array vs. creating a new array, Java

Tags: java, arrays

I'm working on a project where i need to plot some data. At the moment i keep all the data in an object and then give the pointer to this object to the graphs. But it is possible to dynamically change the data, whereas i need to change the data the graphs gets. So here is my question:

Should i create a new array every time i edit the data or and then change the pointers in the graphs or should i just change the data within the original array and the just repaint the graphs?

Comment: There's no real need to create a new array if the old one will do, and you no longer need it's prior values.

Comment: There are no "pointers" in Java.

Comment: @LukasKnuth - Yeah, right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using immutable data results in cleaner, more predictable API. If you mutate the array which is currently used by the graph API, nasty interactions are lurking just around the corner. This may lead to the graph API defensively copying the array internally; at that point you lose: you get more copying than you'd needed had you started with an immutable approach up front.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping one single model is the preferred approach especially from the memory performance point of view. However, it may depend. If you use the same model somewhere else then you must ponder a little bit more.